# Print canvas contents

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

```
var print = document.createElement('button');
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 100;

ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
ctx.font = '15px sans-serif';
ctx.fillText('Fill Text, 18px, sans-serif', 10, 20);

print.innerHTML = 'Print';

document.body.appendChild(print);
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

print.addEventListener('click', function () {
    window.print();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vpetrychuk/LWup5/.

As you can see text in the canvas displays ok, but after clicking "Print" button (and saving page as PDF) output image becomes ugly.

Any chance to print the canvas contents without blur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the actual canvas at print size then scale it on screen using CSS rules.

The browser will always use the internal bitmap size first and adjust that to the print or screen. If the bitmap is then of high resolution you will get better result on the print.

But mind you though, you will need to scale every coordinate and size when you print to the canvas. You will also need to prioritize screen versus print as one of them will look worse (if you prioritize print it will not look super on screen and vica verse).

Here is a **[modified example of your canvas](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/LWup5/1/)** which is now equivalent of 300 DPI (versus default 96 DPI). You can see it looks about the same on screen but will be much sharper when you print it.

```
/// conversion factor for scale, we want 300 DPI in this example
var dpiFactor = 300 / 96,
    width = 400,
    height = 100;

/// set canvas size representing 300 DPI
canvas.width = width * dpiFactor;
canvas.height = height * dpiFactor;

/// scale all content to fit the 96 DPI display (DPI doesn't really matter here)
canvas.style.width = width + 'px';
canvas.style.height = height + 'px';

/// scale all sizes incl. font size
ctx.font = (15 * dpiFactor).toFixed(0) + 'px sans-serif';

/// scale all positions
ctx.fillText('Fill Text, 18px, sans-serif', 10 * dpiFactor, 20 * dpiFactor);
```

Simply use wrapper functions to do all the math for you:

```
function fillText(txt, x, y) {
    ctx.fillText(txt, x * dpiFactor, y * dpiFactor);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to detect when printing is going to happen (e.g. using Webkit `window.matchMedia`) but the actual printing is done using a scaling that is not under your control so creating a perfect 1x1 scaled canvas for sharp graphics is impossible.

You can replace the canvas with an high-enough resolution version when you detect printing, but the exact real size of the output is unknown. It's like if the user has a zoomed view of the page... even if canvas has been drawn sharply the browser can zoom it making the result blurry anyway.

Probably for text the best quality option is using a regular text `div` overimposed on the canvas instead of using `fillText` (of course this won't work for all use cases).

Answer (score 0):

I had in css `width: 100%` for canvas, which caused wrong scaling

Fixed by changing from `100%` to `210mm`

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to use the canvas.toDataURL() method and then set the resulting string to the src of an img. When doing this, generate the canvas through Javascript and never actually append it to the body of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's answer works great. Printing images instead of canvases is better. You don't need to write any JS hacks.

Comment: this should be within a comment, not as an answer

Comment: I don't have reputation to post comments yet, so this was the only way to give credit to the proposed solution.