# Print Canvas element with jqprint

Tags: jquery, css, html5-canvas, jqprint

I have a `signature` in my webpage using a `canvas`. I want to print it with `jqprint`. The print working for everything in the page except canvas element. Do i need to write any css to print signature? Please check it live on my website http://aslobi.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some browsers will unfortunately clear the canvas before printing.

One way to get around this is to insert an image element in the DOM with the canvas and then define two CSS classes:

- One for on-screen hiding the image, showing the canvas
- One for print showing the image, hiding the canvas

Then the key is to update the image with the content of the canvas each time needed.

```js
function updatePrint() {

    var img = document.getElementById('printImage'),  /// get image element
        canvas  = document.getElementById('canvas');  /// get canvas element

    img.src = canvas.toDataURL();                     /// update image
}
```

Then define a couple of CSS rules based on media types:

```css
@media screen {
    #canvas {display:block} /* or inline-block */
    #printImage {display:none}
    }

@media print {
    #canvas {display:none}
    #printImage {display:block}
    }
```

(defining one for screen is strictly not necessary as long as the print definition comes after the standard rule for canvas and image).

Note on print and resolution: when you print a canvas remember that the resolution matters - the screen is typically the equivalent to 72/96 DPI while the print is typically 300 DPI. This may cause the print to look blurry unless you increase the size of the canvas and use CSS to keep it within its screen size. For tips on this see for example this answer: 
[Print canvas contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754961/print-canvas-contents/19756491#19756491). You would also need to handle scaled mouse positions (not covered here).

Note that CORS restrictions apply here in case the canvas has been tainted by different origin images (images drawn to it coming from another domain than the page itself).

Comment: thank you so much, I ask this question more then 5 times here but no one even answer me. You solved my very big problem